# Differences between Shopify Liquid API and Storefront API

Tags: shopify, shopify-storefront-api

I am currently building out a storefront using React and Hydrogen. I am trying to access all types that are used in a collection. The collection object in the Liquid API does return the "all_types" field that lists the desired information. However, the Storefront API GraphQL endpoint does not return this attribute. Am I missing something? Also, if there really are differences between the data than can be returned I'd be curious to know why this distinction is being made.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case you can get a list of product types with Storefront API GraphQL like this:

In the collection object there is a connection with products it contains and the product object has a property called productType.

Please refer to the following documentations:

https://shopify.dev/docs/api/storefront/2023-10/objects/Collection
https://shopify.dev/docs/api/storefront/2023-10/objects/Product

```
{
  collection(id: "gid://shopify/Collection/<YOUR_COLLECTION_ID>") {
    products(first: 250) {
      edges {
        node {
          productType
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. I was hoping there was a way to avoid querying a large chunk of products. But if you say this could be considered best practice here I'd be happy to accept the answer.

Comment: Hey, depends what your use case is really. The example I gave you is per collection as per your question. To get all of the types in the collection you will need to paginate through the results using the pageInfo attribute as the maximum is 250 items each query. Alternatively, you can query all of the productTypes in a store by using the following: [link](https://shopify.dev/docs/api/storefront/2023-07/queries/productTypes)

Comment: Both of those options work well, thank you.